# Postman could not complete Oauth2 login for Microsoft Graph OAuth2

Tags: postman, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use Postman for a Microsoft Graph Rest API OAuth2

I have tried everything mentioned on Stackoverflow and other resources but I cant seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Change **Client Authentication** to **Send client credentials in body**. Also, you should remove the `https://graph.microsoft.com/` bit from your first scope.

Comment: Thank you so much! Please when you have time can you explain the difference between the two?

Comment: OAuth supports sending the parameters within the body or as query parameters. AAD however only supports body parameters.

Comment: @g_altobelli When you select `Send client credentials in body` Postman will send `client_secret` and `client_id` in the request body and when you select `Send client credentials in header` then Postman will first compute Base64('${client_id}:${client_secret}') and then send this in an header as `Authorization: Basic ${encodedValue}`. For more info refer [rfc-6749(section-2.3.1)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-2.3.1)